# XML node depth in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an app that read XMLs files without previously knowing the schema. It is in PHP and I use the following simple code to read and loop through each element:

```
 $reader = new XMLReader();
 $reader->open($fname);
 while ($reader->read()) {
   $depth = $reader->depth;
 }
```

This takes me through every element of the file one by one. I then get the depth and do a graphical representation of the XML file properly indented given that I have the depth element of each node.

I'd like to do this in JS but I can't seem to figure out how. 
The code below loops through all XML elements but I can't retrieve the depth element. I can get the node name, type and value but not the depth... thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (x[i].nodeType == 1) {
            txt += x[i].nodeName + "<br>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: PHP's `XMLReader` appears to visit *all* nodes in a document (in [pre-order traversal order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order), I'm guessing). By contrast, `childNodes` only has the immediate children of the current node, so (at the top level) they're all obviously depth `1`. To go deeper, you'll need to recursively examine the `childNodes` of each child node and keep count of depth yourself as you recurse.

Comment: Yes, it's doable that way, I was hoping for an easier way out of this. Thank you though.